# New mondrian cube not available in XMLA pentaho

Tags: mdx, pentaho, xmla

I have a mondrian cub xml schema file.  I have used it a a basis for an Analysis DataSource.   I can query the thing file with Saiku, and everthing works fine.

However,  when I use olap4j and try to connect to it via the xmla connetor, it does not show up in the list of cubes.  Other cubes show up and can be queried. I set the EnableXmla parameter to true.

Code:

```
        NamedList<Catalog> c = oConnection.getOlapCatalogs();
        NamedList<Schema> l = oConnection.getOlapSchemas();
        Schema schema = oConnection.getOlapSchema("myCube");
        NamedList<Cube> cubes = schema.getCubes();
```

When I print out the list of Catalogs, I can see it, but only one Schema and only one Cube are listed when I print them out.  (Not the one I want of course)

I have refreshed and rebooted the server.  Is there anything else I need to do?